# OWASP ZAP how to fix CSP vulnerabilites, Wildcard Directive and CSP header not Set

Tags: node.js, security, nginx, content-security-policy, owasp

I've search in some security websites how to configure correctly **Nginx server** and **node.js** using **helmet**. But even adding all add_header rules, **OWASP ZAP** software is getting **two medium vulnerabilities**, I would like to know how can I fix it.

The **first one** is related to **robots.txt CSP**

[image: robots.txt medium CSP vulnerability]

I don't know why this is happening I'm not even giving disallow url information in robots.txt, why this is actually a vulnerability?

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml

User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

The **second** medium vulnerability is **CSP Wildcard Directive**

[image: CSP Wildcard Directive vulnerability]

Now I'll share my nginx full configuration and node.js helmet middlewares, maybe I'm forgetting something.

Nginx server configuration:

```
  server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name _;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'report-sample' 'self'; style-src 'report-sample' 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https>
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://gorilafreela.com.br' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection 1;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
  add_header Expect-CT 'enforce; max-age=7776000';
  # gzip
  gzip              on;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      any;
  gzip_comp_level   6;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

  # robots.txt
  location = /robots.txt {
    root /var/www/html;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
  }

  # front-end
  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;
  }
}
```

Node.js and helmet app.js

```
/**
 * Requiring dependencies
 */
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require("helmet");

/**
 * Express app
 */
const app = express();
if (process.env['NODE_ENV'] == 'prod') {
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
            res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
}
app.use(helmet());
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            "default-src": ["'self'"],
            "script-src": ["'self'"],
            "style-src": ["'self'", 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com'],
            "object-src": ['none'],
            "base-uri": ["'self'"],
            "connect-src": ["'self'"],
            "font-src": ["'self'", 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'https://fonts.gstatic.com'],
            "frame-src": ["'self'"],
            "img-src": ["'self'", 'https://res.cloudinary.com'],
            "manifest-src": ["'self'"],
            "media-src": ["'self'"],
            "worker-src": ['none'],

        },
    })
);

app.use(
    helmet.referrerPolicy({
        policy: ["origin", "unsafe-url"],
    })
);
app.use(
    helmet.frameguard({
        action: "deny",
    })
);

app.use(
    helmet.dnsPrefetchControl({
        allow: true,
    })
);

// Sets "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=123456; includeSubDomains; preload"
app.use(
    helmet.hsts({
        maxAge: 31536000,
        preload: true,
    })
);
app.use(
    helmet.expectCt({
        maxAge: 7776000,
        enforce: true
    })
);

app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
app.use(helmet.originAgentCluster());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(loginMiddleware.action);
app.use(roleValidationMiddleware.action);

/**
 * Server port
 */
const port = 3000;
```

Comment: Please share if you have found the solution to these alerts.